# Difference-in-Differences with Repeated Cross-Sections

Tags: survey, difference-in-difference

I have a sample of individuals participating in two survey waves. The sample represents a repeated cross-section because there are different individuals in each survey wave.

Between the waves, there is a shock (i.e., the treatment in a difference-in-differences setup) at the ZIP code level, i.e., some areas (and all individuals living there) receive treatment, while others do not. The problem is that only a small share of areas is observed before and after the treatment (and with different individuals, if so). Therefore, the question is whether I can include people from ZIP code areas where these areas only appear either before or after the treatment. In my understanding, this should be OK as long as the survey participants have been selected randomly. Is this OK?